# Does "chmod 777 .* -R" chmod parent directories (..)?

Tags: linux, shell

Does `chmod 777 .* -R` change the mode of parent directories (..) recursively?

Comment: -> serverfault?

Comment: Not sure what your intended result is.  If you want to chmod everything from the current directory and down, the `chmod -R 777 .`, if you want to only `.` prefixed directories via `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '.*'` this would still include `.`, also the `.*` expands based upon your `$SHELL`, not all shells will expand `.*` to `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. (Learned it the hard way.)

Comment: Didn't wait too long for an answer there, did you? :)

Comment: nice to learn!                   .

Comment: OUCH! (padding)

Comment: You can `echo .*`, if `..` is included in the output, it's probably not the result you're looking for.

Comment: This is true of anything that uses .* - `rm -rf .*` is particularly nasty.

Comment: @jensgram Yep :D Actually, I wanted to put it out there for other newbies so they don't repeat my mistake.

Answer (score 8):

yes.

The use of a recursive option(-r) with a wildcard(*) is almost always a bad idea.

if you were trying this:

```
user@box path/$ foo -r .*
```

which probably means you also did this first, before realizing it missed hidden files:

```
user@box path/$ foo -r *
```

most likely what you wanted to do is

```
user@box path/$ cd ..
user@box $ foo -r path/
```

furthermore, `chmod 777` is always a bad idea.

Comment: nice explanation of the problem and a good alternate way of thinking about it that leads to a real solution.

Comment: Usually these is no need to `cd .. && foo -r prevdirname`. `foo -r .` would usually do the same.

Comment: ah, that brings us to another quirk of mine. I never. ever. ever. ever. run something like that, unless it is something harmless like grep.  running a command like 'chown foo -r .' in the wrong directory can be disastrous.  Going one directory up and typing the name of the directory you really mean to change forces you to pay more attention to what you are doing.

Comment: @justin: that's the alternate behavior i like.  i use `foo -r .` all the time but i'm very very careful with it.  it's still far too easy to forget to check things closely.  getting into a habit & attitude of "no `-r .` ever" is one way to deal with the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Use .??* instead.

Comment: You also need .[^.] if you want to catch entries like `.a`.

Answer (score 0):

Use zsh (which does not match . or .. in ANY glob), or use .[^.]* .??* to match all hidden files. The first part of the glob matches any file that begins with a dot and has as its next character something other than a dot, thus avoiding . and .. The second part matches any file that starts with a dot and is at least three characters long.

To match all files other than . and .. hardlinks, use * .[^.]* .??* , or (on Z shell ONLY) . .*