# Bash path glob matching dotfiles and parent in pwd

Tags: linux, bash

The command

```
$ chmod -R 700 ./.*
```

searches and tries to `chmod` files and directories above the `pwd`. Why?

Expected results: Consider `pwd` is `/home/user`, I would expect the first `.` in `./.*` to be replaced with `/home/user`. Then I would expect the `chmod` applies recursively (`-R`) to all files beginning with a dot (`.*`) in `/home/user`, so: `$ chmod -R 700 /home/user/.*` all together.

I get a slurry of errors like:

```
chmod: cannot access `./../otheruser/file': Permission denied
```

Is this happening because `..` matches `.*`?

Answer (score 6):

`./.*` also matches `./..`, causing `chmod -R` to try recursing everything in `..`.

**Added:**

If you only want the dot files and directories in the current directory, try `.[!.]*`, which matches everything that starts with `.` and has at least one non-dot character following.

If you want all the dot files anywhere in your current directory tree, you can use `find` as shown here using `$(...)` command substitution to paste the output of `find` back onto the command line as arguments to `chmod`.

```
chmod 700 $(find -name ".[!.]*")
```

Comment: Thanks. Then, how might I change ownership/permissions on all the files and directories in a homedir recursively, without recursing into `..`. I mean, `/*` also matches `/..`. So do you know how can I not pick up `..`?

Comment: It appears http://superuser.com/questions/90837/does-chmod-777-r-chmod-parent-directories addresses my question.

Comment: Thanks Nicole. Those are nice, and I also like `cd ..; chmod -R [MODE] /directory`